# Count number of nodes with substring of attribute equivalent to some value

Tags: xml, xpath

Example: trying to count number of b nodes that are images.

XML:

```
<a>
 <b mediatype='image/jpeg'>
  <c>hello.jpg</c>
 </b>
</a>
```

XPath:

```
count(//b[substring(@mediatype, 0, 5) = 'image'])
```

Using the Xpath Tester: http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester
Evaluates to 0.0

Thanks to the answers, have chosen the best answer based on the information given as well as the improved XPath using starts-with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath positions (for lists and strings) start with 1.

If you try `substring(//b/@mediatype, 0, 5)` you will get `imag`.

So you need `count(//b[substring(@mediatype, 1, 5) = 'image'])`

However in this specific case I would suggest `starts-with()`:

`count(//b[starts-with(@mediatype, 'image/')])`

Answer (score 2):

In XPath, indices start at 1.

```
count(//b[substring(@mediatype, 1, 5) = 'image'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the start index that need to be 1.

```
count(//b[substring(@mediatype, 1, 5) = 'image'])
```

Above xpath evaluates to `1.0`

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, the original problem is that xpath index starts from `1` instead of `0`.

Substring from beginning of text can be achieved more conveniently -avoid hardcoding indices- using `starts-with()` :

```
count(//b[starts-with(@mediatype,'image')])
```